# ACM Conference Paper Error - \normalsize is not defined

Tags: graphics, errors, packages, acm

I am using the ACM template from http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/proceedings-template.html .

I get the error:

> The font size command \normalsize is not defined: there is probably
>   something wrong with the class file.

My Document Begins like this:

```
\begin{document}
RequirePackage{graphicx}
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
```

I am modifying the `sig-alternate.tex` file (no explicitly named main file is there).

Comment: always in latex `\documentclass` comes first, then use `\usepackage` then `\begin{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle THanks, I keep getting the error You have requested document class `sig-alternate-05-2015', but the document class provides `sig-alternate'.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In the template I got from the link, there sig-alternate-05-2015.cls and sig-alternate-sample.tex

Comment: That is a bug in their file, but it's only a warning, ignore it (and complain to them:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But in latexilla it is not compiling. I write new content and its doesn't show up in the pdf.

Comment: latex never silently does nothing, it will have left an error message in the log, but if that is a new problem ask a new question with an example that makes the error, don't edit existing questions to ask unrelated new questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document should start (like all latex documents)

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
```

You will get a warning

```
You have requested document class `sig-alternate-05-2015',
but the document class provides `sig-alternate'.
```

which you can ignore, or to stop it, edit the `\ProvidesClass` line in the
file to say sig-alternate-05-2015  or save the file as `sig-alternate.cls` and use

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
```

Probably best just to ignore the warning and complain to the conference organisers and they should fix that bug.

Comment: It is REquirePackAge in my case, it will also be At the same position ?

Comment: @ferrer No you should use `\usepackage`. (`\RequirePackage` works at that point but is the wrong command to use)